# Commenting on SQL Routines in Modules

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11

Is it possible to comment on routines within modules in DB2 11.5 LUW? [CREATE MODULE Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-module) says "COMMENT on objects in the module" is something that can be done with an ALTER MODULE (along with ADD/PUBLISH/DROP). [ALTER MODULE Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-module) makes to mention of commenting, just ADD/PUBLISH/DROP. [Documentation on COMMENT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-comment) doesn't seem to make specific mention of modularized routines, but the [Function/Method/Procedure Procedure Designators](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-function-method-procedure-designators) that it points to does say "a function/procedure designator must not identify a module function/procedure".

Seems weird to be able to comment a procedure, but not a procedure in a module, and hoping I'm just overlooking something.

Comment: You may have found either a documentation-mistake or a coding-mistake. If  you have a support contract, open a ticket. If you don't have a support contract, open a comment on the knowledge-centre page for the 'create module' highlighting the remarks concerning COMMENT on objects in the module.